# Different way to do a same task regularly after a fixed interval of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you please tell me 
Different way to do a same task regularly after a fixed interval of time

I used

```
function setPageIntervale(){
    var timer= setInterval(function() {
        $("#RLTRightDiv").innerHTML='';
        $("#RLTLeftDiv").innerHTML='';
        $.mobile.changePage($("#realTimeScreen"),{transition:'none'});
        clearInterval(timer);   
        setPageIntervale();
        // saveDataOnHtmlFile2();
    }, 15000);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does `setPageIntervale();` do?

Comment: Why do you need a different way?

Comment: If it should only be called once (it appears like this as you clear the interval), have a look at window.setTimeout: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: Please show us what your `setPageIntervale()` function does, as you clear the interval prior to calling this I assume it get reset some how.

Comment: I need to clear the div values after 15 seconds

Comment: I have div , I am getting data from server , my problem is that I want to clear that data after 15 second .But when it clear it clear regularly after 1 sec

Answer (score 1):

If `setPageIntervale()` has to be called every 15 seconds, use this:

```
function setPageIntervale(){
    $("#RLTRightDiv").innerHTML='';
    $("#RLTLeftDiv").innerHTML='';
    $.mobile.changePage($("#realTimeScreen"),{transition:'none'});
    // clearInterval(timer);   <-- remove this
    // saveDataOnHtmlFile2();
}

var timer = setInterval(function() {
    setPageIntervale();
}, 15000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your interval outside of the function :

```
function clearDivs(){
   $("#RLTRightDiv").innerHTML='';
   $("#RLTLeftDiv").innerHTML=''; 
   $.mobile.changePage($("#realTimeScreen"),{transition:'none'});
}

var timer = setInterval(function() {       
   clearDivs();
}, 15000);
```

Alternatively you can use the `setTimeout` function if you require this to only run under a condition.

```
function clearDivs() {
   $("#RLTRightDiv").innerHTML='';
   $("#RLTLeftDiv").innerHTML='';
   $.mobile.changePage($("#realTimeScreen"),{transition:'none'});

   //If you require a condition, set it here.
   if (isTrue) {
      //If the given condition is true clear the divs after 15 seconds.
      setTimeout(function() {             
         clearDivs();
      }, 15000);
   }
}
//Call the div initially after 15 seconds
setTimeout(function() {             
   clearDivs();
}, 15000);
```

Based on your comment, if you want the divs to clear after 15 seconds the first time, then 1 second every time after that, do the following :

```
function clearDivs() {
   $("#RLTRightDiv").innerHTML='';
   $("#RLTLeftDiv").innerHTML='';
   $.mobile.changePage($("#realTimeScreen"),{transition:'none'});

   //Re-Call this function every 1 second.
   setTimeout(function() {
      clearDivs();
   }, 1000);
}
//Clear the divs after 15 seconds.
setTimeout(function() {
   clearDivs();
}, 15000);
```